# Comparing 2 String Arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Im trying to write a simple program that will take 2 multi line inputs from 2 textboxes, put them in 2 arrays and compare them.

I want to check if an entry in array 1 (each line of textbox 1 is a separate entry in array 1) is in array 2 (each line of text box 2 is a separate entry in array 2).

then output the results to a textbox.

for example:

Array 1 "one, two, three, four, six"

Array 2 "one, three, five, four"

it should output:

```
one = found
two = not found
three = found
four = found
six = not found
```

The code i have so far is as follows:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         textBox3.Text = "";
         string[] New = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
         string[] Existing = textBox2.Text.Split('\n');


       //for each line in textbox1's array
        foreach (string str in New)
        {

            //if the string is present in textbox2's array
            if (Existing.Contains(str))
            {
                textBox3.Text = "   ##" + textBox3.Text + str + "found";
            }
            /if the string is not present in textbox2's array
            else

            {
                textBox3.Text = "    ##" +textBox3.Text + str + "not found";
            }
        }


    }
```

This is not working correctly if there is more than one line in the either textbox - i cant figure out why.. the following is happening in test runs:

```
Array 1 - "One"
Array 2 - "One"
Result = One Found


Array 1 - "One"
Array 2 - "One, Two"
Result = One Not Found


Array 1 - "One, Two"
Array 2 - "One, Two"
Result = One found, Two Found

Array 1 - "One, Two, Three"
Array 2 - "One, Two"
Result - One Found, Two Not Found, Three Not Found
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and seeing what the contents of `textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text` are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is not working correctly if there is more than one line in the either textbox - can anyone figure out why?

You should work on diagnosing problems yourself - I suspect that a simple breakpoint just before the loop, following by examining the arrays, would find the issue immediately.

I'm pretty sure the problem is just that you should be splitting on `"\r\n"` instead of `'\n'` - currently you'll end up with a rogue `\r` at the end of all lines other than the last one, which will mess up the results.

Rather than using the `Text` property and then splitting it, you could just use the `Lines` property instead:

```
string[] newLines = textBox1.Lines;
string[] existingLines = textBox2.Lines;
...
```

EDIT: As noted in Guffa's answer, you will *also* want to avoid replacing `textBox3.Text` on each iteration. Personally I'd probably use create a `List<string>`, add to it on each iteration, then at the end use:

```
textBox3.Lines = results.ToArray();
```

Comment: Exactly.  The TextBox control has a Lines property that will give you exactly what you want: an array of individual lines.

Comment: @w.brian: Indeed, I was just editing to show that very approach :)

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` can also be used for splitting

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much - i had been looking at iterations with loops and all sorts of things, i never thought the actual array generation could be the issue. Thanks again - will mark as answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the force, Luke:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t', '\n', '\r' };
string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
```

Added '\r' to delimiters.

Comment: Actually I don't think that will help, as written - it'll still leave `\r` at the end of all lines but the last one... and I don't see anything in the question suggesting that the OP wants to split each line into words.

Comment: Ok, it was a general answer. Yours is more specific, but will leave commas and other symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code (just change the `int` to `string`):

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var b = new[] { 7, 8, 11, 12 };

// mixing the two arrays, since it's a ISet, this will contain unique values
var c = new HashSet<int>(a);
b.ToList().ForEach(x => c.Add(x));

// just project the results, you can iterate through this collection to 
// present the results to the user
var d = c.Select(x => new { Number = x, FoundInA = a.Contains(x), FoundInB = b.Contains(x) });
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] New = textBox1.Text.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
string[] Existing = textBox2.Text.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var str in New)
{
    sb.AppendLine(str + (Existing.Contains(str) ? " found" : " not found"));
}
textBox3.Text = sb.ToString();
```